# unexpected error when i edit comment in a modal then return to the comments modal and delete it

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

when i open the modal of comments and press the edit button it open another modal then i edit the comment and press the edit button and close the edit modal and the changes are made and the comment is edited but when i press the delete button on the same comment it give me that error

**TypeError: null is not an object(evaluating 'snapshot.val().commentTxt')**

and **'snapshot.val().commentTxt'** is inside the edit function not the delete function so why does it appear only when i press the delete button -knowing that the delete button work and delete the comment and it is not affected by the error-

here is the edit and delete code :

```
editComment = () => {
        firebase.database()
        .ref(`posts/${this.props.postKey}/comments/${this.state.editCommentKey}`)
        .on('value', snapshot =>{
            if (this.state.editComment === snapshot.val().commentTxt){
                this.setState({editCommentModalVisible: false})
            }
            else{
                firebase.database()
                .ref(`posts/${this.props.postKey}/comments/${this.state.editCommentKey}/commentTxt`)
                .set(this.state.editComment)
                this.setState({editCommentModalVisible: false})
            }
        })
    }
    deleteComment = (item) => {
        firebase.database().ref('posts').child(this.props.postKey/*'-M0IviCqMGE_PxoqNd0W'*/)
        .on('value', snap => {this.makeCommentIncrement =  snap.val().commentsNumber})
        this.makeCommentIncrement= this.makeCommentIncrement-1
        firebase.database().ref(`posts/${this.props.postKey}/commentsNumber`).set(this.makeCommentIncrement)
        firebase.database().ref(`posts/${this.props.postKey}/comments/${item.commentKey}`).remove()
        .catch(error => {
            alert(error.toString())
            return
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `someRef.on('value', someFunction)`, you add a listener. The function `someFunction` is executed every time the data at `someRef` changes. These listeners have to be detached manually (see [Detach listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#detach_listeners)), or you can use `once` instead of `on` (see [Read data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once)).

When you delete a comment, you change the data at the comment's ref (you make it null), so `snapshot.val().commentTxt` gives you an error, because `snapshot.val()` is null.